# How do I display nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let para = document.createElement('p');
document.body.appendChild(para)

const apple = { 
  color: 'Green',
  price: {
   bulk: '$3/kg',
   smallQty: '$4/kg'
  }
};

let txt = ''
for (let x in apple) {
  txt += apple[x] 
 };

para.innerHTML = txt;
```

In the browser, I'm getting Green[object Object] thank you

///////////////

Comment: And what result do you expect instead?

Comment: Try `txt += JSON.stringify(apple[x])`. Also, the `price` key is an object, for `price` key you have to loop again to access `bulk` and `smallQty`.

Comment: Always try to add what is your expected result. This way others can assist you in a better way.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Reading your code it almost seems like you just want to do `para.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(apple)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2nd iteration, you are getting an object which is why you are seeing such an output.
Convert `apple[x]` to a string using `JSON.stringify(apple[x])` and this will be your output:

***"Green"{"bulk":"$3/kg","smallQty":"$4/kg"}***